# How to do two validation checks on an array without looping two times

Tags: javascript

I have got an array of JS objects on which I want to do few validation checks. It should do the following checks with the priority in the order given.

1. Check if the value is correct. (obj.value == 'valid')
2. Only one object should have value. Other should be empty.
3. Value of all objects empty is also an invalid option.

Based on these checks, all invalid objects should have a msg property gets added to it with the proper message. I have created the function for this. However, this doesn't seem like a good solution. I am looping through array two times to get the correct msg. Is there a good way?

Please note that, it should be compatible with IE8. array methods like every will not work.

Please see the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/K2Y7F/

```
var arr = [{
    value: 'valid'
}, {
    value: ''
}, {
    value: 'someinvalid value'
}];

function validate() {
    var counter = 0,
        moreThanOneItemSelected = false,
        noItemSelected = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].msg = '';
        if (arr[i].value.length > 0) {
            if (arr[i].value != 'valid') {
                arr[i].isValid = false;
                arr[i].msg = 'This is an invalid value';
            }
            counter++;
            noItemSelected = false;
        }
        if (!arr[i].msg) {
            arr[i].isValid = true;
        }
    }

    if (counter > 1) {
        moreThanOneItemSelected = true;
    }
    if (noItemSelected) {
        for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
            arr[k].isValid = false;
            arr[i].msg = 'Need to set atleast one item';
        }
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            var currItem = arr[j];
            /*invalid item*/
            if (currItem.isValid && moreThanOneItemSelected && currItem.value.length > 0) {
                currItem.isValid = false;
                currItem.msg = 'add only one item';
            }
        }
    }

}
validate();
console.log(arr);
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What defines item selection ? `noItemSelected == false` only if there is an invalid item present !

Comment: I don't see a reason to loop more than once to achieve it

Comment: @MK. noItemSelected becomes true, if all the objects in the array don't have value. (value property)

Comment: @lombausch: u mean, not to loop more than once? I was just checking if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @jintoppy you should divide message logic and you data logic. "Add only one item" message is not related to the object but to all objects so you should keep it somewhere else. that way you will not need to loop through it multiple times if you find second value set to 'valid'

Answer (score 1):

As you have an action that depends on scanning all items, and requires updating scanned items based on the final result, there is no way to do this in one loop, your best option is to save references of valid items, then loop over them if more than one item is selected.

**Best case scenario**: You have only 1 valid value (you wouldn't loop the array again).

**Worst case scenario**: All items in the array are valid (you will loop the valid values array, same as looping the same array again).

**Update**

I re-read your post another time, and what I got is:

1. **VALID**:

   - Only one item having value == 'valid', others should be empty.
2. **INVALID**:

   - All empty.
   - More than one none empty item either valid or invalid.

If the above is true, then you definitely have to perform a revisit after scanning the items:

```
function validate(arr){
    var firstValidItem = null;
    var containsInvalid = false;
    var mightRevisit = [];    
    for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
        var item = arr[x];
        switch(item.value){
            case 'valid':
                // only one valid item is allowed.
                if(firstValidItem){                    
                    item.msg = 'add only one item';
                    item.isValid = false;
                }else{
                    firstValidItem = item;
                    item.isValid = true;
                }
                break;
            case '':
                //empty is considered valid at this point
                item.isValid = true;
                mightRevisit.push(item);
                break;
            default:
                //this is invalid regardless of others
                item.isValid = false;
                item.msg = 'This is an invalid value';
                containsInvalid = true;
                break;
        }            
    }
    //if no valid item found, all empty items should become invalid
    if(!firstValidItem){
      for(var x=0;x<mightRevisit.length;x++){
        mightRevisit[x].isValid = false;
        mightRevisit[x].msg = 'Need to set atleast one item'; 
      }
    }else if(containsInvalid){ 
        //any invalid items makes the valid item invalid.
        firstValidItem.isValid = false;
        firstValidItem.msg = 'add only one item';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzLj2/

**Best case scenario**: `[{value: 'valid'},{value: ''},{value: ''}];` you'll not loop `mightRevisit` array.

**Worst case scenario**: `[{value: ''},{value:''},{value: ''}]` you'll loop `mightRevisit` array which is equal to a second loop of the original array.

Comment: Hm. All items in the array are valid will be possible when only one item has the value and the other all item values are empty. There should be always only one valid value. But, invalid value can be more than 1. obj1 - validvalue, obj2 - empty, obj3- empty (valid scenario), obj1-validvalue, obj2 - validvalu, obj3 - validvalue (invalid scenario)

Comment: Yes, exactly! your logic says if more than one item has value == 'valid' then all valid - 1 items matching the same criteria will be considered invalid .. correct ?

Comment: suppose obj1 has valid value. But, obj2, obj3 can have either valid or invalid value right? So, depends on that, obj1 can become invalid. Hope I didn't confuse you :-)

Comment: I didn't like the idea of adding several if/switch conditions in a for loop. But, its just a personal preference only. Thanks

Comment: As I said, there is no way to do it without a second loop, just wrote that to clarify my point :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this structure:

```
arr_obj = {
  is_valid: true,
  msg: "Bingo you got a valid stuff",
  arr:[ ... your array ]
}
```

than I would loop through arr_obj.arr

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr_obj.arr.length; i++) {
  // your validation logic
  // if found anything invalid than set arr_obj.is_valid = false and msg as well
}
```

the key is not mixing up messaging and data structure. your array object is invalid only if more than one or zero elements are set to 'valid' thus you should stick the message to your array object not to individual items.

Comment: 1. An array object is not valid or invalid in this scenario. Each object in array only will get the status of valid or invalid.              2. object can become invalid on 3 scenario. if every object value is empty, then also, the object is invalid. Or, if the value of the object is anything other than the value 'valid', then also the object is invalid